# apply fromiter over matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iteration

Why does fromiter fail if I want to apply a function over the entire matrix?

```
>>> aaa = np.matrix([[2],[23]])
>>> np.fromiter( [x/2 for x in aaa], np.float)
array([  1.,  11.])
```

This works fine, but if the matrix is 2D, i get the following error:

```
>>> aaa = np.matrix([[2,2],[1,23]])
>>> aaa
matrix([[ 2,  2],
    [ 1, 23]])
>>> np.fromiter( [x/2 for x in aaa], np.float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What alternate can I use?
I know i can write 2 loops for rows and columns, but that seems slow and not pythonic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you decide to go down the `np.fromiter` route, at least make your iterator a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a multidimensional matrix iterates over the rows, not the cells.  To iterate over each value, iterate over `aaa.flat`.

Note that `fromiter` (as documented) only creates one-dimensional arrays, which is why you have to iterate over the cells and not the rows.  If you want to create new matrix of some other shape, you'll have to reshape the resulting 1d array.

Also, of course, in many cases you don't need to iterate at all.  For your example, you can just do `aaa/2` to divide every element of the matrix by 2.

Comment: Thanks Bern, that does work, but i was hoping for something where my resulting object was a matrix of the same dimension as the original?

Comment: @adi: The `aaa/2` solution does that.

Comment: Thanks again, yes aaa/2 is possible (my actual code is more complex, this was just for a example)

Comment: @adi: If you have a more complicated function, look at using `np.frompyfunc` to make a `ufunc` from your function.  The ufunc will then be applied elementwise if you call it on a numpy object.